# How to fill transparent area by content aware in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I exported a panorama from autopano. It seems to have only one layer, and there're a lot of transparent area. How do I fill it with content aware?

[image: sample of the transparent part]

I can crop it if photoshop's content aware can't handle such an enormous area, but how to fill it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might not work too well, if the area is large, but...

- Magic Wand [w] [click in the empty area, of course]
- Edit menu > Fill...
- Contents > Content aware

[image]

I had a quick attempt & screenshotted it with the selection showing...

[image]

Try it in smaller sections if doing it all at once isn't too good.
You can use Marquee & deselect areas that aren't working.
Repeat with the wand & grab whatever is left - do it in stages.

Comment: Thanks! But your solution didn't work for me... Somehow I can't select the transparent area!

Comment: Here is my screen shot: [link](http://imgur.com/2H8Fi5v)

Comment: current tool showing is Quick Selection, not Magic Wand

Comment: If you get regions of transparent pixels at the edge of the selection after applying the Fill, you may need to tweak the Magic Wand parameters or the selection itself.

In my case, I needed to expand the selection by 10 pixels before applying Fill (Select menu -> Modify -> Expand)

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed! Works even with gradients and multiple regions with different colors.